# What is the best way to analyse this set of data using Matlab?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

i'm trying to analyse some data i collected but i'm not sure i'm doing it right.

I have data collected from a test in which people are presented a sequence of numbers and then they have to answer with the same sequence, but in inverse order.
The answers can be:

- correct (C),
- correct numbers but wrong order (WO);
- wrong (W).

I have collected data for the selection time of each number in each sequence. I have data from 4 patients.
I would like to analyse if there are difference in times between the 3 groups above.

My thinking process is as follows:

1. normality test on the data, i used the Lilliefors test on each group of C, WO, W. normality rejected
2. i think i should use a non parametric test to search for difference between groups.
   If i'm correct, the assumptions for Kruskal-Wallis test are:

- independent samples,
- distribution is the same in order to evaluate the median of the groups;
  Here i'm not sure how to consider my data, first of all if they are independent.
  Secondly how to check for distribution in order to correctly evaluate the median.

3. At last, if the non parametric test rejects the hypothesis H0 i think i should run a post hoc analysis on the data. Here i also have doubts on what i should do.

I tried to do a resume of the problem i'm trying to solve, for anything i'm here to give more details.
Thanks to anyone who could try help me figure this out.

Edit1:
[image: histogram of reciprocal for selection times of correct answers]
[image: histogram for selection times of correct answers]
[image: histogram of reciprocal for selection times of wrong order answers]
[image: histogram of reciprocal for selection times of wrong answers]

I ran a Lilliefors test using Matlab to check for normality.
If I use the selection times i get H0 rejected, so no normality.
If I use the reciprocal I get normality distribution for each group.

Comment: Use of Matlab is immaterial here.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I used Matlab because it's the environment i'm most familiar with, but you're right, my main concern here is on the theory behind it more than how to run the analysis. I tried to explain my thinking process but i'm not sure it's the right way to conduct the analysis. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Fine, but there is no need to mention Matlab at all then.

Comment: I think we need to see what the selection times look like. There is no obvious need to retreat to nonparametric tests. Log or reciprocal of time may helo,

Comment: Thanks again. I edited the main post with some new informations. I tried to do what you suggested me, hope I got it right. Using reciprocals I get normality distribution accepted using Lilliefors test, so it seems I could run Anova on the different groups to check for differences. Still, I'm not sure why i get this result transforming to reciprocals. Another question I still have is, how should I consider my samples? Can i consider them independent, though they are collected from 4 individuals and registrations of correct, wrong order and wrong comes from all the subjects?

Comment: The reciprocal of time is a rate (e.g. a speed of thought or action). It is part empiricism, part principle that rates are often more nearly symmetric than times to do things.  Whether your samples are independent is a question best addressed to people in your field.

Comment: Thanks, you've been really helpful Mr. Cox.